# What are some best practices for properly unsubscribing from observables in Angular to avoid memory leaks and improve application performance?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, mean-stack

What are some best practices for properly unsubscribing from observables in Angular to avoid memory leaks and improve application performance?

In Angular, observables can be used to subscribe to data streams, such as events, HTTP requests, and other async operations. However, if observables are not properly unsubscribed, it can result in memory leaks and negatively impact the performance of an application. To prevent this, it's important to understand the best practices for unsubscribing from observables in Angular. This question aims to gather information on the recommended approaches and techniques for properly unsubscribing from observables to maintain the health and performance of an Angular application.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule],
  template: `
  <div *ngFor="let data of responseData">
  <h1>{{data?.title}}</h1>
   <img [src]='data?.thumbnailUrl'>
   </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnDestroy {
  subscription = new Subscription();
  responseData:any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
 this.subscription= http
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
      .pipe(map((data: any) => data?.slice(0, 5)))
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.responseData=data;
      });
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
    if(this.subscription){
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Is takeUntil is better that this

Comment: The "takeUntil" it's good when you have a lot of subscriptions. If only have one subscription it's good simply unsubscribe this function. BTW, it's good practice use services to return observables based in httpClient, not directly use it in the component

Answer (score 2):

I use a subscription array in my components and
when I use a subscribe  method ,I push its return value in my subscription array ,finally in ngOnDestroy in a loop every item of array will be unsubscribed.
I use this way like you for many years,
this post will be useful if others share their solution.
thanks